# Metal semiconductor Junction

Tags: semiconductors, schottky, pn-junction, electron, metal

As we know in normal p-n junctions is formed by doping on a single semiconductor so that material continuity is maintained which facilitates the movement of charge carriers between two regions. But in case of metal-semiconductor junction, there wont be any material continuity as metal is deposited over the silicon substrate. Then how electrons movement takes place??

Comment: Why do you think that there won't be "material continuity"? Also, what do you exactly mean by that? Metal can be deposited on silicon in a number of ways, and you do have material continuity...

Comment: yes, actually that's where i made mistake in thinking. Deposition is a chemical process and continuity will be there anyhow. Thanks Vladimir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fermi levels of both materials have to be equal, which will cause some band bending of the semiconductor at the interface - this will lead to a gradient for enabling electron movement.